# OOP PHP class extends TwentyTwenty_Customize in Child Theme

Tags: php, theme-customizer, oop

Not sure if OOP is covered here but i've copied the class-twentytwenty-customize.php file from the Twenty Twenty parent theme to my child theme and renamed it to class-customize.php because i need to modify it and add more settings to the customizer, but i get errors.

I changed line 16 from this

```
class TwentyTwenty_Customize {
```

to this :

```
class TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended extends TwentyTwenty_Customize {
```

What am i missing

I'm loading the class in my child theme like this

```
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/class-customize.php';
```

**Update:** Warning:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended' not found in /Users/michelle/Desktop/local/app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307
```

This is the code in class-customize.php:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', array( 'TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended', 'register' ) );
function register() {

if ( ! class_exists( 'TwentyTwenty_Customize' ) ) {
    return;
}

    class TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended extends TwentyTwenty_Customize {

        public static function register( $wp_customize ) {

// Default code.


    $new = new TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended;

    $new->register( $wp_customize );

}
```

Comment: What’s the error you’re receiving?

Comment: `class 'TwentyTwenty_Customize_Extended' `not found

Comment: What does `class_exists( 'TwentyTwenty_Customize' )` return? Are you in a namespace?